# dragging/scrolling along a path with Raphael

Tags: jquery, raphael, draggable, scrolltop

I was able to get an object to move along a path while scrolling, but I'm hoping to add functionality to drag the ball along the path while it scrolls the page. Nothing I've tried works, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's a jsfiddle for anyone who would like to see that.
http://jsfiddle.net/jaruesink/StD6X/

```
$(function() {
    Raphael("holder", 640, 480, function () {
        var r = this,
            p = r.path("M247.832,261.211c-19.408-10.846-33.492-47.748-41.123-66.572c-12.574-31.018-30.738-92.277-7.552-122.189c5.511,16.652,2.014,40.018,1.926,57.407c-0.27,52.703-6.908,101.25-15.773,153.008c-6.166,36-15.068,130.735-72.547,124.382c-6.258-12.716,13.125-24.068,20.445-31.353c39.967-39.779,84.457-79.047,115.439-126.593c27.893-42.807,46.109-101.534,49.13-152.602c2.344,7.983,1.338,20.379,1.142,29.666c-0.639,30.025-2.233,60.371-4.255,90.35c-2.612,38.754-15.235,77.743-15.627,116.299c-0.917-12.587,3.64-23.74,5.717-35.99c5.285-31.148,12.264-61.737,18.527-92.772c5.347-26.499,8.268-53.483,13.611-79.963c1.68-8.321,4.4-39.25,14.637-43.116c29.602-11.173,32.101,72.19,31.265,84.899c-0.989,15.104-17.456,63.116-42.325,54.414c-6.874-2.406-12.237-10.499-6.491-16.326c29.989,34.912,8.484,106.492,57.719,129.61c52.633,24.716,167.903-33.98,158.341-98.086").attr({stroke: "#666", opacity: .3, "stroke-width": 10}),
            len = p.getTotalLength(),
            e = r.circle(0, 0, 5).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#fff"}).onAnimation(function () {
                var t = this.attr("transform");
            });
        r.customAttributes.along = function (v) {
            var point = p.getPointAtLength(v * len);
            return {
                transform: "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
            };
        };
        e.attr({along: 0});



        var rotateAlongThePath = false;
        var offset = $('body').scrollTop();
        var bheight = $('html').height() - $(window).height();
        var bpercent = offset/bheight;
           e.attr({along:bpercent});  
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        function run() {
            var offset = $('body').scrollTop();
            var bheight = $('html').height() - $(window).height();
            var bpercent = offset/bheight;
           e.attr({along:bpercent});
        }
        run();
    });



  });
  });
```

Comment: +1 I think you did a great job with this, nice example.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck progressing this further? I'd like to animate on window scroll, much like you have (nice work!). I was just wondering if you stuck with Raphael or moved on to a tool more suitable?

Comment: Sorry for the few months delay. I put it in this drive folderL https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B5teN9F_jc5uSFpQaVp1RG9RTzQ. Raphael was the best way to use custom svg. Let me know if you figure anything else out.